# ERRORS in Makefile with subfolders

Tags: gcc, makefile, subdirectory

I have a project with a lot of subfolders :

[image: My project tree]

And I am trying to write a Makefile which can compile everything into a single .exe.
Here is my Makefile :

```
#Makefile


CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -O3

SRC = $(wildcard */*.c)

OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

all : Executable

Executable : $(OBJ)
    gcc -o Executable  $(OBJ)

#transforme tous les .c en .o
%.o : %.c
    gcc -o $(OBJ) -c $(SRC)

clean:
    rm Executable
    find . -type f -name "*.o" -exec rm {} \;




#END
```

However, it does not work very well.
I have errors with the clean :

```
find . -type f -name "*.o" -exec rm {} \;
cc  -o clean  
cc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:21: clean] Error 1
```

And also with the compilation :

```
gcc -o construct_grid/construct_grid.o detect_boxes/detect_boxes.o detect_character/detect_character.o errors/errors.o fileManager/fileManager.o preprocessing/preprocessing.o solver/solver.o -c construct_grid/construct_grid.c detect_boxes/detect_boxes.c detect_character/detect_character.c errors/errors.c fileManager/fileManager.c preprocessing/preprocessing.c solver/solver.c
gcc: fatal error: cannot specify ‘-o’ with ‘-c’, ‘-S’ or ‘-E’ with multiple files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:17: construct_grid/construct_grid.o] Error 1
```

What is wrong with my Makefile, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> I have errors with the clean :
>
> ```
> find . -type f -name "*.o" -exec rm {} \;
> cc  -o clean  
> cc: fatal error: no input files
> compilation terminated.
> make: *** [Makefile:21: clean] Error 1
> ```

There is nothing in the makefile presented that explains why `cc -o clean` would be executed during a `make clean`.  Or ever.  If you've presented the full makefile then I can only suppose that it is not being used directly, but rather by being `include`d into some other makefile that is responsible for introducing the extra command.

On the other hand, this ...

> ```
> gcc -o construct_grid/construct_grid.o detect_boxes/detect_boxes.o detect_character/detect_character.o errors/errors.o fileManager/fileManager.o preprocessing/preprocessing.o solver/solver.o -c construct_grid/construct_grid.c detect_boxes/detect_boxes.c detect_character/detect_character.c errors/errors.c fileManager/fileManager.c preprocessing/preprocessing.c solver/solver.c
> gcc: fatal error: cannot specify ‘-o’ with ‘-c’, ‘-S’ or ‘-E’ with multiple files
> compilation terminated.
> make: *** [Makefile:17: construct_grid/construct_grid.o] Error 1
> ```

... is a consequence of this incorrect rule:

> ```
> %.o : %.c
>     gcc -o $(OBJ) -c $(SRC)
> ```

A pattern rule such as that should have a recipe that builds *one* file matching the target pattern from its corresponding prerequisites.  Your `$(OBJ)` expands to the names of *all* the wanted object files, and `$(SRC)` to the names of *all* the corresponding sources.  That the compiler does not accept the resulting command is a side issue.  Additionally, the rule does not make use of the compilation options set in your `CFLAGS` variable.

You appear to want something more like this:

```
%o: %c
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

The `$@` is an automatic variable that expands to the name of the target being built (one of the .o files in this case), and the `$<` is another automatic variable, which expands to the name of the first prerequisite in the list.

Or you could even omit that rule entirely, because `make` has a built-in rule that does a substantially equivalent thing (but not identical, because the built-in rule recognizes some additional variables that you are not using).